# How do I get jquery object with js function work simultaneously in a single page

Tags: jquery, function, object

I need jquery object and non-jquery function to work in a single page. This is what I have in my head

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
    $('a.mini-view').click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
        var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
        if (!clicked){
            var newValue = $('#hiddenfield').val() + "," + value;
            $('#hiddenfield').val(newValue);
            $(this).attr("clicked", true);
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function toggle2(showHideSpan, switchTextSpan) {
             var ele = document.getElementById(showHideSpan);
             var text = document.getElementById(switchTextSpan);
             if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                             ele.style.display = "none";
                     text.innerHTML = "Answer";
             }
             else {
                     ele.style.display = "block";
                     text.innerHTML = "Hide";
             }
     }
</script>
```

jquery does not work. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the jQuery script tag and keep it empty:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, there's no need to escape quotes in Javascript if you want them to be treated as strings.

```
<script>
    $('a.mini-view').click(function(){
        var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
        var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
        if (!clicked){
            var newValue = $('#hiddenfield').val() + "," + value;
            $('#hiddenfield').val(newValue);
            $(this).attr("clicked", true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your jquery code inside ready function like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.mini-view').click(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked");
    var value = $(this).attr("data-student");
    if (!clicked){
        var newValue = $('#hiddenfield').val() + "," + value;
        $('#hiddenfield').val(newValue);
        $(this).attr("clicked", true);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A `<script>` tag may not have both a `src` attribute (for loading external files) *and* script contents.  It can only have one or the other.

Also, there's no need for the `type` attribute - these days it's implicit.